# Best way to get all Futures in a Dask collection

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

If one has a Dask collection `d` that depends on some persisted content, what is the best way to get a list of all `Future`s that `d` depends on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want the function

```
dask.distributed.client.futures_of
```

which is also available as a method of a `Client`.